# vgui is a nil value Gmod

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I've been trying to do a mod for gmod, that includes derma panel. But when I try to use that derma, error appears.

```
AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" )
include("shared.lua")

function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()   
    return false
end

function SWEP:SecondaryAttack()
    DermaPanel()
end


function SWEP:Reload()
    return false
end

SelectedPower = "Stasis"

function DermaPanel()
    local Frame = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
    Frame:SetPos(650,500)
    Frame:SetSize( 585, 150 )
    Frame:SetTitle( "Biotic Powers" )
    Frame:SetVisible( true )
    Frame:SetDraggable( false )
    Frame:ShowCloseButton( true )
    Frame:MakePopup()

    local bpush = vgui.Create( "DButton", Frame )
    bpush:SetText( "Push" )
    bpush:SetSize(100,30)
    bpush:SetPos(25,100)

    local bpull = vgui.Create( "DButton", Frame )
    bpull:SetText( "Pull" )
    bpull:SetSize(100,30)
    bpull:SetPos(135,100)

    local bstasis = vgui.Create( "DButton", Frame )
    bstasis:SetText( "Stasis" )
    bstasis:SetSize(100,30)
    bstasis:SetPos(245,100)

    local blift = vgui.Create( "DButton", Frame )
    blift:SetText( "Lift" )
    blift:SetSize(100,30)
    blift:SetPos(355,100)

    local bbarrier = vgui.Create( "DButton", Frame )
    bbarrier:SetText( "Barrier" )
    bbarrier:SetSize(100,30)
    bbarrier:SetPos(465,100)
end
```

When I try to open up derma panel with secondary fire, this error appears:

```
"[ERROR] addons/mass effect biotics/lua/weapons/weapon_biotics.lua:59: attempt to index global 'vgui' (a nil value)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling it in shared it is being run on both server and client. If the error is blue it is because the vgui table doesn't exist on the server and is erroring in the server instance but it is running perfectly ok in client-side.

You can put it in an if CLIENT statement and everything will be ok.

Comment: BTW: Just as a reminder: Questions and answers here are not limited to a small number of characters. Thus, please don't use the abbreviations which are normal for situations where the number of characters you are permitted is quite limited. In other words, please use normal English.